# Redirect Non-www to www URLs but it doesn't work well?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, no-www

I'm using a `.htaccess` code that change the url (add 'www.' in non-www urls) but my problem is when entering /subfolder in url , `.htaccess` redirect doesn't work right.

**Example**

I enter this url: **mydomain.com/demo/** it redirects to: **www.mydomain.com** (without `/demo`)
any idea?

Here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where under your www root directory is your .htaccess file located, and what is your RewriteBase set to?

Comment: my .htaccess file is  in /root/demo folder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|local|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomainhere.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi sir , no it doesn't work!  check my site http://arcadebooster.org I put your snippet code in .htaccess file  in "/demo"  subfolder but it doesn't work again .

Comment: But then your main site is in /demo, so either put the main site to the root, or add one more line to the top of your .htaccess RewriteBase /demo/, after rewriteEngine

Answer (score 0):

I have changed that code and put it in root path, it works well :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]    
</IfModule>
```

the .htaccess file  should be placed in /demo folder but when I move its location to /demo folder  I saw that it can't redirect well.

ie : http://mydomain.com/demo/?querystring   redirect =>   http://www.mydomain.com/?querystring

the problem is that  'demo/' in url is eliminated .

do you have any idea?

Comment: Don't post further questions as answers, the answer has an edit button

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for adding `www`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, if an .htaccess file is placed in a subfolder of your www root folder, then the name of the subfolder is [stripped from the path before it's passed to the rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> "When using the rewrite engine in `.htaccess` files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the RewriteRule pattern matching and automatically *added* after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive for more information regarding what prefix will be added back to relative substitutions."

Thus, the `^(.*)$` regex in your rewrite rule, which is *supposed* to match the entire path and save it in `$1`, is actually only matching the part of the path *after* the `demo/` prefix.

To fix this, you have two options:

- a) Move your .htaccess file (or at least this particular rewrite rule) to the www root folder.  If you, for some reason, still want it to only match paths under the "demo" folder, replace the `^(.*)$` regex with e.g. `^(demo(/.*)?)$`.
- b) Add the folder name back yourself, making your rewrite rule look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/demo/$1 [R=301,L,NS]
```

(I also added the [`NS` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ns), since you probably want it for "cosmetic" external rewrites like this.)